# Send Texture2d object to function

Tags: c#, function, xna-4.0, texture2d

I try to send some object to a function but seems C# doesn't like that. This is the code.

```
string[] bkgrSource = new string[12];
Texture2D[] bkgrBANK = new Texture2D[12];
```

which `bkgrSource[0]` is an array of filenames and `bkgrBANK[0]` is an array of `Texture2D`.

This function is not working. The `bkgrBANK[0]` will remains empty. Any help?

```
commonImageLoader( bkgrSource[0], bkgrBANK[0] ); 

private void commonImageLoader(string source, Texture2D destination ) {
    if ( !string.IsNullOrEmpty( source ) ) {
        fileName = source;
        using ( fileStream = new FileStream( @fileName, FileMode.Open ) ) {
        destination = Texture2D.FromStream( GraphicsDevice, fileStream );
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a C# guru, but I think the point is that you are passing parameter by value (default method call behavior),
So source and destination parameters in your function are a copy of the original ones.

I think you can pass parameter [by reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645763%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) to solve this issue.
Probably this should work:

```
commonImageLoader( ref bkgrSource[0], ref bkgrBANK[0] ); 

private void commonImageLoader(ref string source, ref Texture2D destination ) {
    if ( !string.IsNullOrEmpty( source ) ) {
        fileName = source;
        using ( fileStream = new FileStream( @fileName, FileMode.Open ) ) {
        destination = Texture2D.FromStream( GraphicsDevice, fileStream );
        }
    }
}
```